# Intersection of more than 2 mesh objects

Tags: mesh

I've managed to select the intersection edges of 2 given mesh objects, using Wiltor Jaworski's plugin (http://airplanes3d.net/scripts-253_e.xml).

However, I couldn't find any reference as to how to get the (possible) intersection of more than 2 objects.

For example, if I have 3 planes A, B and C that intersect in a given point, how can I select this point?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a way to do this. It is not ideal, but it works and is also non-destructive. Select one of the meshes that is part of the intersection. Add a Boolean modifier to it, choose one of the other objects as the Object in the Boolean modifier. Copy that modifier and chose the other mesh as the Union Object this time. After yo do this there will be a vertex at the intersection

1. Select one of the meshes, any will do (A)
2. Add a Boolean modifier to it:

   - Operation: Union
   - Object: one of the other ones (B)
3. Copy the Boolean modifier

   - Object: the other one (C)
4. Optional: If you would like to use the intersection in edit mode to move around mesh components. If all you want to do is to get the intersection just add the empty

   - add an empty, plain axis will do fine
   - snap the empty to the intersection: Set the snapping type to vertex. The empty acts as a vertex in this case
   - in edit mode snap the geometry to the empty if you want to.

Note: You can delete the modifiers when you no longer need them.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Using two modifiers did the job very well. However, could you elaborate on the 'Snap' method a little, starting from your point #4? How can I snap the geometry to the empty -- not sure what it means either ?

Comment: Set the snapping type to vertex. The empty acts as a vertex in this case

Comment: Indeed. Got the intersection point using an empty axis and the Magnet icon.

Comment: there are also shortcuts for the snapping. Ctrl + Tab to turn on snapping. Ctrl + Shift + Tab to set what to snap to.

Comment: @Vader It's Shift+Tab (you probably already knew that, but just in case others don't..)

Comment: @gandalf3 oops it is indeed

Comment: there are also shortcuts for the snapping. Shift + Tab to turn on snapping. Ctrl + Shift + Tab to set what to snap to

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of **Boolean** modifier:

1. Adding a **Boolean** modifier to Object A, Operation: Union, Target: B;
2. Adding second **Boolean** modifier to Object A, Operation: Union, Target: C.
3. Apply both modifiers to find the point, or use another vertex or empty to snap on that intersection point.

[image]